# PHP Problem: else condition not executing

Tags: php

```
function procLogin( $user, $pass, $remember, $hostname, $domainame )
{ 
  global $session, $form;

  $retval = $session->login( $user, $pass, $remember );
  if ( $retval )
  {
    if ( $session->userlevel == 9 )
      if ( $session->isAdmin() ) 
        return ( array( 
          $session->userlevel, $session->userid 
        ) );
  } else { 
    $process = new process( );
    //process->s_Host('domain.com');
    //$process->s_Domain('domain.com');
    $process->s_Host( $hostname );
    $process->s_Domain( $domainname );
    $process->s_processSecure( false );

    $process->s_User( $user );
    $process->s_Pass( $pass );
    // First check we actually have a username and password set inside the process object.
    if ( $process->g_User() && $process->g_Pass() )
    {
      if ( $process->processConn() )
      {
        if ( $process->processBind() )
        {
          return 'google';
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My problem is if the login is false, why does it not turn towards else condition....

if i remove the code inside else part and put return 'no' it does work.... i just want to know why the code inside the else part does not execute

Comment: What specifically isn't working?

Comment: Is it never executing? Are you getting error messages? Can you provide any more information?

Comment: Formatting the brackets might help you see what is going on :P

Comment: Your bracketing style is very, very inconsistent. I'm wondering how you even read your own code.

Comment: My problem is if the login is false, why does it not turn towards else condition....

Comment: There are 8,608 questions currently tagged PHP - so a question titled "PHP Related Question" is a bit vague.  You may want to specify what your actual problem is in the question, and give additional information in the actual content of the question.

Comment: I formatted the code and updated the title for you

Answer (score 7):

`$session->login(...` must somehow always evaluate to true. You would probably be better off posting the code of the login method.

Comment: My problem is if the login is false, why does it not turn towards else condition....

Comment: Try assigning false to $retval without the call to login and see if that works.

Comment: +1 This is going to be it, I'm willing to bet. $retval is evaluating to TRUE every time.

Comment: Not like that Karim.... if i remove the code inside else part and put return 'no' it does work.... i just want to know why the code inside the else part does not execute.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe login is returning `"false"` as a string? It is evaluating to true because it is not null.

Answer (score 1):

Without a specific error or details of the implementation, or a hint that the PHP runtime or builtin or library is broken ...

This looks like a case of **go back, check, debug**.

Comment: My problem is if the login is false, why does it not turn towards else condition....

Comment: Becuase, it is not false, or your control flow is poor. The if statement processing is not broken.